How to Access Direct Buffer Used by Tomcat for Sockets in a Servlet's doPost Method?
I'm currently working with Apache Tomcat web server, and I came across a feature mentioned on the official Tomcat website regarding socket.directBuffer support. This implies that Tomcat can use direct buffers for socket communication.
My goal is to access the buffer used by the socket in the doPost method of a servlet. However, I'm not sure how to retrieve or interact with this direct buffer within my servlet code.
Here is a simple outline of my servlet:
@WebServlet("/api")
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // How can I access the direct buffer here?
    }
}

My Questions:

Is it possible to directly access the direct buffer used by Tomcat for socket communication within a servlet's doPost method?
2.If yes, what is the proper way to retrieve this buffer?
Are there any potential pitfalls or considerations when working with direct buffers in this context?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I had search through internet but, i didn't got any hint

In a word, no. You interact with the container via the specified interfaces, that’s it.

What kind of socket do you like to access?

OP is talking about Tomcat's NIO socket, Roman. See also the link and question's tags.

So here we cannot use a channel, right? The only possible way is to receive data from the input stream, which is the request body, and send that data to the file channel for the writing process. The JNI copy of the buffer cannot be avoided, right?
